# Programmatically Create Fake Bluetooth Device in Android

Tags: java, android, c++

I was wondering if there is any way to create a fake bluetooth device in an android activity/service?

For example you launch the app, go to the bluetooth menu in the phone, and you would be able to see/connect to the fake device

Comment: Why? Making it appear would be one thing, but what would it do?

Comment: @DavidRawson I'm not talking about BlueStacks, I'm talking about bluetooth. The protocol.

Comment: Well then it's too broad, especially since you have tagged it with `java` and `c++`. BTW did you read "how to ask"?

Comment: @DavidRawson I did, and my question is not broad, it is just the question.

Comment: Think about what you are asking. Have you looked at the relevant Android classes? BluetoothDevice has a private constructor and delegates to a native method. And how would an app present the device to the Android system? You would need to write a custom ROM. But I guess that's not too broad, right?

Comment: He wants to add a mock device to the bluetooth scan result list and allow  apps to use it.

Comment: Any way to achieve this